# Auto-formatting a source file in emacs

Tags: emacs, formatting

How do I apply a set of formatting rules to an existing source file in emacs?

Specifically I have an assembly (`*.s`) file, but I would like a generic command for all types of files.

I am trying to use `M-x c-set-style` with `gnu` style, but I am getting an error:

> > Buffer *.s is not a CC Mode buffer (c-set-style)

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Open the file and then indent it by indenting the entire region:

```
M-x find-file /path/to/file RET
C-x h                             (M-x mark-whole-buffer)
C-M-\                             (M-x indent-region)
```

Now, it looks like you're trying to apply C indentation to a buffer that's not in C mode.  To get it into C mode

```
M-x c-mode
```

Or `c++-mode`, or whatever mode you want.  But, since it's assembler code, you probably want assembler mode (which Emacs will do by default for .s files).  In which case, the indentation command above (`C-M-\` is also known as `M-x indent-region`) should work for you.

Note: the command sequence at the top can be rolled into a single command like this:

```lisp
(defun indent-file (file)
  "prompt for a file and indent it according to its major mode"
  (interactive "fWhich file do you want to indent: ")
  (find-file file)
  ;; uncomment the next line to force the buffer into a c-mode
  ;; (c-mode)
  (indent-region (point-min) (point-max)))
```

And, if you want to learn how to associate major-modes with files based on extensions, check out the [documentation for auto-mode-alist](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Choosing-Modes.html).  To be fair, it's not necessarily extension based, just regular expressions matched against the filename.

Comment: Best with emacs questions to note what the keystrokes bind to. I.e. `M-<` is usually bound to `beginning-of-buffer`. Use `C-h k` for keystroke help.

Comment: Also, `C-x h' (mark-whole-buffer) selects everything in slightly fewer steps, and works even if you are using transient-mark-mode.

Comment: @Jouni, thanks for C-x h, I didn't know about that.  incorporated the solution.

Comment: Not working in 25.1.1
wrong number of arguments: (lambda (numSpaces) (progn ( ....

Comment: @Maven Need more information.  Works great in my 25.1.1.  The wrong number of arguments shows a `numSpaces` which I don't see in the code I wrote above, leading me to believe there's some other dependency that you're not showing.

Comment: My bad. There was a custom defun indent-region overriding the default one. Figured it out. Your code is fine.

Answer (score 7):

Try `M-x asm-mode`.  That will switch to assembler mode.  Not sure how it will go with assembler embedded in the middle of a C file.

Answer (score 4):

if you want indent current buffer

```
(defun iwb ()
  "indent whole buffer"
  (interactive)
  (delete-trailing-whitespace)
  (indent-region (point-min) (point-max) nil)
  (untabify (point-min) (point-max)))
```

Comment: this is perfect. I did add-hook to before save. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

emacs will use the file name extension to identify the mode, you should add some assemble language mode style in your custom.el file

Answer (score 0):

The major mode it's using for your .s files won't be cc-mode hence c-set-style makes no sense. However you can always manually enter cc-mode (M-x cc-mode) and then do the c-set-style you want. However as the C styles are keyed for C source code and not assembler this is almost certainly *not* what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to indent from the command line use :

```
emacs --batch  <filenames.v>  -f verilog-batch-indent
```

Comment: Your command line is interesting. I would have rather add: `emacs --batch code.c -f mark-whole-buffer -f indent-region --eval "(princ (buffer-string))" 2>/dev/null`. So that the code is echoed to the terminal