# window--display-buffer: How to precisely set window width at time of creation

Tags: emacs, elisp

With respect to the function `window--display-buffer`, I have been unable to precisely set the window width using **a number** -- e.g., `'((window-width . 82))`.  The width is always slightly less than it should be.  Any assistance to reliably use **a number** to set the window width would be greatly appreciated.

The documentation ( https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Display-Action-Functions.html ) states as follows:

To adjust the window's width, use an entry whose **car** is `window-width` and whose **cdr** is one of:

- `nil` means to leave the width of the new window alone.
- **A number** specifies the desired width of the new window. **An integer number** specifies the number of columns of the window. **A floating point number** gives the fraction of the window's width with respect to the width of the frame's root window.
- If the `cdr` specifies **a function**, that function is called with one argument: **the new window**. The function is supposed to adjust the width of the window; its return value is ignored.

---

Here is a `broken-example` that demonstrates the problem with `window--display-buffer` when using **a number** -- e.g., `'((window-width . 82))`

```lisp
(defun broken-example ()
  (interactive)
  (window--display-buffer
   ;; buffer
   (get-buffer-create "*test*")
   ;; window
   (split-window (selected-window) nil 'right)
   ;; type
   'window
   ;; alist
   '((window-width . 82))
   ;; dedicated
   t) 
  (message "Window Width:  %s" (window-width (get-buffer-window "*test*"))) )
```

---

Here is a `working-example` that uses *the third option* -- i.e., **a function** whose argument is **the new window**:

```lisp
(defun working-example ()
  (interactive)
  (window--display-buffer
   ;; buffer
   (get-buffer-create "*test*")
   ;; window
   (split-window (selected-window) nil 'right)
   ;; type
   'window
   ;; alist
   '((window-width . set-window-width))
   ;; dedicated
   t)
  (message "Window Width:  %s" (window-width (get-buffer-window "*test*"))) )

(defun set-window-width (window)
  "Set the selected window's width."
  (window-resize window (- 82 (window-width)) t) )
```

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Comment: @sds -- I would be happy to learn how to better format the code.  I suffer from OCDC and need to have everything a certain way.  Would you like me to create one long line for `window--display-buffer` and remove the helpful comments regarding what each of the variable components stands for?  If I do that, then everyone will need to use describe-variable to see what each of the components are for.

Comment: Just use Emacs to indent your code and learn to like that style. ;-)

Comment: @sds -- okay -- I selected `emacs-lisp-mode`, selected the region, and then used `indent-region`.  I used this link as a guide:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/992863/2112489

Comment: The "--" in the function name says that it's internal, IOW "use at your own risk".

Comment: @Stefan -- thank you for taking a look at this thread.  My goal was to figure out why several of the `display-buffer` family of functions were not setting the `window-width` correctly when using the `alist` with a `number` format -- e.g., `'((window-width . 82))`.  Inasmuch as **eleven (11)** of the `display-buffer` family of functions rely upon `window--display-buffer`, I believe that it is important for this *internal* function to work correctly.  The following comment contains a list of all the `display-buffer` functions that are at affected:

Comment: What appears to be a bug is at lines 5937 to 5947 of `window.el`.  The following functions use the *internal* function `window--display-buffer`:  **(1)** `display-buffer-in-atom-window`; **(2)** `display-buffer-in-major-side-window`; **(3)** `display-buffer-in-side-window`; **(4)** `display-buffer-same-window`; **(5)** `display-buffer-reuse-window`; **(6)** `display-buffer-pop-up-frame`; **(7)** `display-buffer-pop-up-window`; **(8)** `display-buffer-below-selected`; **(9)** `display-buffer-at-bottom`; **(10)** `display-buffer-in-previous-window`; **(11)** `display-buffer-use-some-window`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As to a current version of Emacs Trunk built on March 19, 2014, the following modification of line 5944 of `window.el` from <strike>`(delta (- new-width (window-total-width window))))`</strike> to `(delta (- new-width (window-width window))))` resolves this issue.

**EDIT** (March 22, 2014):  Here is a link to the open bug report on this issue -- http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=17065